# How to check whether an element is exists in another Arraylist

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

For example we have two ArrayList

```java
ArrayList<Integer> first = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> second = new ArrayList<>();
```

And lets say we add some numbers to them:

```java
first.add(1);
first.add(2);
second.add(2);
second.add(3);
```

And how to check here the condition like:

```java
if(first.contains(second(element))){cnt++;(just increment hypothetical counter)}
```

Thanks

Comment: I am trying to check if an element from first exists in another and opposite 
I want to count the number of integers that does not exists in another array(unique ones)

Comment: @BakhtovarUmarov So you want to know the number of elements from the first in the second?

Comment: @Abra yes, but how to run a loop that would go through two arrays, I tried vide double for (i, j) but its not compiling

Comment: @iota I want to know the number of integer like this:(!first.contains(second.get(ELEMENT))

I want to find out which loop to use and how

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Stream` API to filter and count the elements in the second list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> first = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> second = new ArrayList<>();

        first.add(1);
        first.add(2);
        second.add(2);
        second.add(3);
        second.add(2);

        first.forEach(n -> System.out
                .println(n + " exists " + second.stream().filter(e -> e == n).count() + " times in the second list"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 exists 0 times in the second list
2 exists 2 times in the second list
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Collections#frequency`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) to print the frequency of each number of the list, `first` in the list, `second`:

```
for (Integer x : first) {
    System.out.println(x + " exists " + Collections.frequency(second, x) + " times in the second list");
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the nested loops to iterate the list, `second` for each number in the list, `first`:

```
for (Integer x : first) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Integer y : second) {
        if (x == y)
            count++;
    }
    System.out.println(x + " exists " + count + " times in the second list");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess it too difficult solution for many people. For beginner kind of hard to understand

Comment: @BakhtovarUmarov - If you can tell me the part of the code which you found hard, I can help you understand the same.

Comment: so foreach it has own count()?

Comment: No, it's [`Stream#count`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--). Learn more about `Stream` API from [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html) and [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html) tutorials.

Comment: @BakhtovarUmarov - I've added two more ways to do it. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler version of code. I wasn't quite sure from the question what exactly you are looking for. So I have added code for two methods.

1. One that returns count of unique elements which are not present in list 2 but available in list 1.
2. The other method returns map with element and count of occurrence of that element present in both the lists.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         ArrayList<Integer> first = new ArrayList<>();
         ArrayList<Integer> second = new ArrayList<>();

            first.add(1);
            first.add(2);
            first.add(2);
            first.add(2);
            first.add(2);
            first.add(4);
            second.add(2);
            second.add(3);
            second.add(2);
            second.add(1);
        
        int uniqueCount = getCountOfUniqueElements(first,second);
        Map<Integer,Integer> countMap = getCountMap(first,second);
        System.out.println("Count of unique Elements in First list that are not in second list="+uniqueCount);
        countMap.forEach((key,value) -> System.out.println(key + " occurred " + value + " times in first list"));

        
    }

    /**
     * Counts number of elements that are in first list but not in second list
     * @param first
     * @param second
     * @return count
     */
    private static int getCountOfUniqueElements(List<Integer> first,
            List<Integer> second) {
        
        if(first == null || first.isEmpty() || second == null || second.isEmpty()) //if lists are empty or null, count is 0
            return 0;
        
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(second); // Convert second list to set for faster search or constant time retrieval 
        int count = 0;
        for(Integer element : first) {
            if(!set.contains(element)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        
        return count;
    }
    
    /**
     * Counts number of elements that are in first list which are also available in second 
     * list
     * @param first
     * @param second
     * @return map with key as first list element and value as number of its occurrences in first list
     */
    private static Map<Integer,Integer> getCountMap(List<Integer> first,
            List<Integer> second) {
        
        if(first == null || first.isEmpty() || second == null || second.isEmpty()) //if lists are empty or null, return emptyMap
            return Collections.emptyMap();
        
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(second); // Convert second list to set for faster search or constant time retrieval 
        Map<Integer,Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>(); // Maintains count of occurrences of first list element present in second list.
        for(Integer element : first) {
            if(set.contains(element)) {
                countMap.put(element, countMap.getOrDefault(element, 0)+1);
            }
        }
        
        return countMap;
    }
```